# JSON to Jolt specification array

Tags: jolt

I have a JSON of one of the nodes like below

```json
"origin": {
        "site": "XXXXXX",
        "service": "XXXXXXXX",
        "accountId": "1001472060",
        "transactionId": "112477870",
        "group": {
            "type": "LE",
            "referenceId": "2141"
        }
    }
```

I need to convert the jolt specification like below

```
"subscriberIds": ["account_id","PMLE_ID"]

"subscriberIds": ["12121212","121212"]
```

Could you please shed some lights on the above?

Comment: I have tried like below, ,\"spec\":{\"subscriberIds\":{\"0\":\"variables.payload.accountId\", \"1\":\"variables.payload.group.referenceId\"}...its not working

Comment: it's hard to understand what are you trying to perform. Which one is the desired output that has no common point with the input which has invalid syntax too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...The desired output would be -> "subscriberIds": ["12121212","121212"]

Comment: I need to take the input from the JSON from   "origin": {
        "site": "XXXXXX",
        "service": "XXXXXXXX",
        "accountId": "1001472060",
        "transactionId": "112477870",
        "group": {
            "type": "LE",
            "referenceId": "2141"
        }
    }